# iMacros: export error by missing tag to csv

Tags: csv, tags, extract, imacros

i export data from a webpage to a csv with a fixed number of columns.
When a tag is missing, the macro ignores it and proceed to the next tag.
As result, this tag is also missing in the csv an there is no data for the column.
Because of that, the data from the next tag is placed in the column for the missing tag...
That's a mess.

Is there any solution to export an error code for missing tags?
So i can delete them later and my columns are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When iMacros doesn't find the text/element/whatever on the page it gives result #EANF# .

You can use if clause and make a statement about #EANF# . This means you have to use javascripts and there are quite a lot of example on how to use JS and iMacros on stackoverlow.

Comment: My macro doesn't give the result #EANF#. There is no extraction at all? :(

Comment: OK, I got it... SET !ERRORIGNORE was YES instead of NO